# How to change qtconfig option in 'cmake' to qtconfig4?

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, kde-plasma, kde4

While configuring krita, I am getting a `cmake` error saying `Unable to compile a basic Qt application.  Qt has not been found correctly.` I think the reason is there is a conflict between the QT5 and QT4 dev packages. What to do?

```
sricharan@sricharan-Lenovo-Z580:~/kde4/build$ sudo cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$HOME/kde4/inst $HOME/kde4/src/calligra -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -DPRODUCTSET=KRITA
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.2
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.2
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Calligra version: 2.9 Pre-Alpha
-- Release build: TRUE
-- -------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Configured with product set "KRITA"
-- -------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Looking for Q_WS_X11
-- Looking for Q_WS_X11 - not found
-- Looking for Q_WS_WIN
-- Looking for Q_WS_WIN - not found
-- Looking for Q_WS_QWS
-- Looking for Q_WS_QWS - not found
-- Looking for Q_WS_MAC
-- Looking for Q_WS_MAC - not found
-- Found Qt-Version 5.2.1 (using /usr/bin/qmake)
-- Looking for include file pthread.h
-- Looking for include file pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Found Automoc4: /usr/bin/automoc4  
-- Found Perl: /usr/bin/perl (found version "5.18.2") 
-- Found Phonon: /usr/include (Required is at least version "4.3.80") 
-- Performing Test _OFFT_IS_64BIT
-- Performing Test _OFFT_IS_64BIT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_FPIE_SUPPORT
-- Performing Test HAVE_FPIE_SUPPORT - Success
-- Performing Test __KDE_HAVE_W_OVERLOADED_VIRTUAL
-- Performing Test __KDE_HAVE_W_OVERLOADED_VIRTUAL - Success
-- Performing Test __KDE_HAVE_GCC_VISIBILITY
-- Performing Test __KDE_HAVE_GCC_VISIBILITY - Success
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
QT_QT_INCLUDE_DIR
   used as include directory in directory /home/sricharan/kde4/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed

CMake Error at /usr/share/kde4/apps/cmake/modules/FindKDE4Internal.cmake:1311 (message):
  Unable to compile a basic Qt application.  Qt has not been found correctly.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindKDE4.cmake:95 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:146 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I am not sure, but maybe the reason is that it QT5 but KDE4 requires QT4. I have installed required `libqt4` libraries  but that won't help. What should I do?

Please tell me if I am inferring the errors in a wrong way.

Comment: Okay. The build was successful. I just had to `apt-get autoremove` some of the conflicting dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the QT_SELECT env variable. (apt-get install qtchooser)

Example

```
export QT_SELECT=4
```

or

```
export QT_SELECT=qt4
```

Answer (score 0):

`export QT_SELECT=4` and `export QT_SELECT=qt` no longer seems to work in `cmake` 2.8.12.2, the variables have to be `cmake` variables, i.e. run

```
cmake . -DQT_QT_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/qt4/ -DQT_SELECT=4
make
```

to compile

Answer (score 0):

Some build files don't take into account the use of environment variables, so it is not an error attributable to cmake.